# ListView won't let me set <List> as my list

Tags: android, listview

I have a list:

```
  Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

I want to set this in my adapter. I have tried this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<List>(this, R.layout.listview_row_customizations, pkgAppsList) {
```

But I'm getting an error **cannot resolve constructor array adapter...**

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.listview_row_customizations, pkgAppsList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The List in new ArrayAdapter is not correct, instead write your object class type (ResolveInfo).

if you need custom layout (I guessed this because you are not using a string list but an object with a few parameters) - follow this instructions:

build your own custom ArrayAdapter:

```
    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ResolveInfo> list) {
        super(context, 0, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvPriority = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriority);

        tvName.setText(resolveInfo.resolvePackageName);
        tvPriority.setText("" + resolveInfo.priority);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

create a layout named item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity, call it by:

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, pkgAppsList);
```